# Can one propose a new SE site for a topic which has been already closed as a beta?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, beta-sites, closed-sites

There was a [proposal for an Arabic Language SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language) closed after 61 days in beta.

Can one suggest to re-open such a closed beta site after several years? There may be increased attention and public interest in the topic.

Comment: There's a *specific* potential issue here - that SE, last I recall, didn't really feel that non english sites were something they could effectively manage. When the non english SOs were started they had dedicated CMs who could communicate in those languages. Hiring those isn't really an option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [this meta Area 51 answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10367/223582) Robert states:

> Closing a site does not mean folks cannot try again… if they have reason to believe they can make a better go of it the second time around. I'm not speculating whether *this* particular subject is ready to try again, but we could just as easily have closed Big Data in the proposal stage. When we close proposals for lack of an audience, we often [encourage users to gather more support to try again](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5798/5). Big Data simply got a bit further along than most.
>
> At times, we may close proposals/sites that simply should not be their own Q&A. But I don't believe sites closed for *other* reasons should be used as a head-on-a-stack gesture that they should *never* become sites at all — *"We already tried this; it didn't work. Go away!"* That's not how Area 51 works.

Then about four minutes after that answer was posted the OP of the question left [a comment on the answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/duplicate-of-closed-proposal-does-that-make-sense#comment16774_10367):

> I see the proposal has been reopened. Thanks! – user72809  [May 10, 2013 at 15:56](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10363/duplicate-of-closed-proposal-does-that-make-sense#comment16774_10367)

Where *the proposal* was [Data Science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053?phase=definition) which was launched five years ago.

On the [beta page for the Arabic language proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62022/arabic-language) it has this text:

> This site has been
>
> ### Closed
>
> This proposal didn't have enough activity during the beta. It was closed 7 years ago.
>
> You could try [proposing a variation of this site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=culture) that you think will have a better chance.

Clicking [that link](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=culture) leads to a form for a new proposal. If there is belief that there would be enough community support for such a site then it can be proposed.